# Non-EU spouse of a British national, living in the EU. Do I need a visa for the UK?

Tags: visas

I live in the Czech Republic with my husband and kids, who are British, but I am not. I'd like to travel to the UK for a few days on my own. Can I still apply for an EU family member's visa?

Answer (score 2):

> Non-EU spouse of a British national, living in the EU. Do I need a visa for the UK?

It depends on your nationality, unless you are traveling with your spouse and you have a residence card stating that you are the family member of an EU citizen.  Because you want to travel without your spouse, ...

> Can I still apply for an EU family member's visa?

No.  More precisely, you can apply, but you should expect a refusal.  If the EEA family permit is granted, you will not be able to use it.

The EEA family permit is valid only if you travel to the UK with your EEA family member or, if your EEA family member is already in the UK, you travel to join him or her there.  See https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eligibility.

To travel independently to the UK, you will need a [Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa), unless you are a citizen of a country whose citizens enjoy visa free entry in the UK.  You can check that at https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa.